Connector identification (Mitsubishi MAC-567IF-E)
I would like to ask if someone knows what connector exactly is this - it is used in Mitsubishi HVAC Wifi adapter (PN: MAC-567IF-E). I extracted this one from the adapter itself, but I would rather buy a new one - including the corresponding plug if at all possible.
Pin pitch seems to be 1mm (maybe 1.2mm or similar - definitely smaller than the 1.27mm board I have used for this temporary adapter), 11 pins in one row, latch on top.
It seems to be quite similar to JST NSH, but that is not the correct one. I saw similar ones from JST, Molex and one more company, but could not find an exact match.
Front view:

Top view:

Dimensions (in mm, top view):


Where's Davide when we need him?

I was in Texas to see the eclipse. I am back now.

I was not sure what Davide @Colin was talking about. But I was clicking around and found out, that it is probably the Davide, who created this tool: https://connectorbook.com/identification.html
I did not know something like that existed and I used it to narrow down my search to Molex Micro-lock 504195-1170  Too bad that this particular variant (11 pin) is not readily available almost anywhere or the minimal quantity for order is something like 1200pcs - but I will keep searching 
Thanks Davide, I'm gonna go & buy your book!
